# Why does this regex work in angular 1 and not in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular

Why does this regex in Angular 1, given as:

```
ng-pattern="/(([\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u01BF].*){2,})|^[\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u01BF]{1}$/"
```

validates correctly `..ba`

but translated into this Angular 2 code not.

```
Validators.pattern("/(([\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u01BF].*){2,})|^[\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u01BF]{1}$/")
```

... even with having the slashes removed:

```
Validators.pattern("(([\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u01BF].*){2,})|^[\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u01BF]{1}$")
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you try to remove the regex delimiters, double the backslashes: `\\u...`

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes `Validators.pattern("/blahblahblah/")` to  `Validators.pattern(/blahblahblah/)`. Scrap that. that a look here it might help https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11159

Comment: We tried the double backslashes, providing the regex as string or as regex... in different variants. Doesn't work. Unfortunately we need a more concrete answer.  Guys... anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to provide a fiddle? BTW, the pattern is very suspicious, could you please provide the actual requirements and some sample strings that should match and not match?

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew ... yes, probably. I'll ask the colleague for it... he left the office for today. Dziękuję.